# Is it possible to install both android and mono for android in a same system?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have already installed android sdk and eclipse IDE in my system which is window 7 and want to install mono for android development in my system.But after the installation of mono for android development my android apps in eclipse didnt run.

Comment: Yes - both should run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - both should run fine.

Mono for android sits on top of android sdk but does not modify it.

I've been running both fine for the last year.

Whatever the issue is with your eclipse installation can be worked out it you post specific details of the error you are seeing.

Comment: First I installed Android SDK n eclipse Helios n java 7.my android prgms executed fine but when i installed mono for android development my android prgms didnt run.my sdk manager didnt open.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. Xamarin help people have been no help so far. I can see nobody here has any thoughts either so far. If I figure it out I'll be back.